# Selenium Webdriver Web crawler

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would ask you something, do you know how to create web crawler using selenium webdiver? to find all elements of web included sub folder

Thanks you

Comment: Yes I do ... question answered :)

Comment: can you tell me to how to do it?

Comment: Yes, google Selenium, and start reading the documentation!!!

Comment: The point of the comments above: this question is too broad for this site. You need to ask a more specific question that is likely to have a short and clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

Even though, I did not do it practically but following link may help you.

1. [Selenium-Crawler](https://github.com/corywalker/selenium-crawler)
2. [Crawlin a website with Selenium-Webdriver](https://www.hackerearth.com/notes/praveen97uma/crawling-a-website-that-loads-content-using-javascript-with-selenium-webdriver-in-python/)

Answer (score -1):

You could give a try to [Serritor](https://github.com/peterbencze/serritor). Serritor is an open source web crawler framework built upon Selenium and written in Java.