# How to web crawl on Google

Tags: java, proxy, web-crawler, jsoup, search-engine

My requirement is to make a report on a given keyword by searching that keyword online.

My plan is that my webcrawler will

1. Search the keyword on google or bing or yahoo
2. Open pages/links of the website returned by google, bing or yahoo
3. Make the report using those pages.

As I want to make a rule obeying webcrawler. So when I see the `robots.txt` of these websites I come to know that search engines have blocked the webcrawler to search keywords like

*google.com/robots.txt*

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /search
```

I know that if I try to search keyword on the search engines my ip might be blocked.

My new plan that my webcrawler will

1. Search the keyword on google or bing or yahoo *( max 2 - 3 times
   in different span of time a day)*
2. Open pages/links of the website return by google, bing or yahoo
   *(giving 2 - 3 mins of delay in opening each page/link returned by search engine)*
3. Make the report using those pages.

**Questions**

1. Let me know that even after so much care will google block my ip
   ? Is it safe to webcrawl like that ?
2. Also let me know good techniques for using proxies to hide/change
   actual ip address.

PS: I am using Java and Jsoup for webcrawling

Comment: You should probably use the Search APIs provided by the search engines. That way you won't get blocked (although the searches are still limited).

Answer (score 0):

Try **selenium**, to do your job.Its for automation so i don't think your ip will block by any of the service provider.

Comment: Its a testing software. Can you let me know that how might this be helpful ?

Comment: Just like any human click's on web-page , you can do this by using selenium, people use this for testing or monitoring production servers. At  the same time when you hit some url or link or click anywhere in web-page, you can harvest the data from page using standard java code. This link will be helpfull for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804319/selenium-webdriver-web-crawler

Comment: I donot want to crawl specific urls. As keywords are unknown so we cannot determine the number websites and urls to be crawled.